# R S4class containing list of another S4class

Tags: r, lapply, r-s4

I have an issue verifying the validity of my class 'class2'; it is made of a list of 'class1' objects. I want to verify that it is indeed the case:

```
class2 <- setClass(

    Class = "class2",

    slots = c(slotListName = "list"),

    validity = function(object){

             lapply(object@slotListName, function(x){

            if(!identical(is(x), "class1"))
                stop(" not a class1 object");
        });            
    });
```

The problem is that lapply returns values which are not accepted:

```
Error in validObject(.Object) : 
invalid class “class2” object: 1: NULL
invalid class “class2” object: 2: NULL
```

I checked that the problem was coming from the lapply by testing only the first element of the list, which is working fine:

```
if(!identical(is(object@slotListName[[1]]), "class1"))
       stop("not a class1 object");
```

I tried vectorizing but this does not change the problem.

Is there a way to verify that slotListName is indeed a list of 'class1' objects?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you want to happen if there are no class1 objects? Should `slotListName` be NULL or a list of length 0?

Comment: I want the constructor to throw an error and the class 2 object not to be created. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your function is that it gives an error for an invalid object. It's supposed to return a diagnostic message, with the S4 object construction machinery taking care of the error.

Here's how you can do it using the recommended approach, which is to define methods for `initialize` and `setValidity`. See `?setClass` for more details.

```
class2 <- setClass("class2", slots=c(slotListName="list"))

setMethod("initialize", "class2", function(.Object, lst)
{
    .Object@slotListName <- lst
    validObject(.Object)
    .Object
})

# returns TRUE if the object is valid, otherwise a diagnostic message
setValidity("class2", function(object)
{
    if(length(object@slotListName) < 1)
        "must contain at least one class1 object"
    else if(!all(sapply(object@slotListName, function(x) inherits(x, "class1"))))
        "all objects in list must be class1"
    else TRUE
})


## testing
x <- 42
class(x) <- "class1"
y <- 43
class(y) <- "bad"

l1 <- list(x, x, x)
l2 <- list(x, x, y)


## works
obj1 <- class2(l1)

## error: bad object in list
obj2 <- class2(l2)

## error: empty list
obj3 <- class2(list())
```

Comment: got it! Thank you very much.